# would a LED placed in reverse protect the switch from arcing?

Tags: led, switches

[image]would a LED placed in reverse protect the switch from arcing?

[image]

Comment: Use a schottky instead.

Comment: That led won't do anything. It's shorted out.

Comment: No, it wouldn't. The diode would have to be placed across the *motor* to prevent arcing in the switch. Also, an LED is very atypical for this. You need a power diode, either PN or Schottky, for this application.

Comment: LED's have a very limited reverse breakdown voltage. Even if you place it correctly, it is liable to fail when it is reverse biased. High power white LED's intended for illumination applications are even less tolerant of reverse voltage.

Comment: 'using a LED to protect something' - 'so who won? I used my nose to smash his fist! Owww!'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No an LED is typically NOT capable of serving as a flyback (or snubber or commutating) diode. Unless you have an inductive load that is so tiny you probably don't need a flyback diode. Simply use a proper power diode (1N4003, etc.) And the diode is placed ACROSS the inductive load, not the switch or the power supply.

Comment: actually my choices were a relay, snubber or diode. but it seems that putting a diode across a load is much simpler and smaller (it fits in the limited space) that's why i was hoping there is a "large led that exists."

is it true that arcing occurs both during opening and closing of the switch? if yes, would a diode placed across the load protect the switch on both events?

Comment: A diode IS a "snubber" (unless you mean something else, please explain). Not clear why you were looking for a "large LED" if you have "limited space"? The snubber diode will NOT prevent switch arcing. That is a completely DIFFERENT problem with a different solution.  You did not mention any details (voltage, current, etc.) so we don't know what you are dealing with here.  Consider using a transistor to do the switching.

Comment: actually the problem is about a mosquito zapper (picture above) powered by two AA batteries. at first, i tested everything and everything seems fine. there's even continuity on the switch. but it only works when the batteries are newly charged and it wont work anymore after a few minutes, so i have to charged the batteries again. so i tried to changed the switch, and now it works even after several days. so i assumed that the switch is at fault here, maybe arcing.